# Craft - suitability for membership/user registration and document upload/management

Tags: users, login, registration, pdf, member

I have created about 30 sites using Perch but find it somewhat frustrating, especially the support. Considering using Craft for my next project but can it handle:
Membership/user registration. Ie can i restrict certain sections of the iste to registered individuals or members?
Document management. The prospective client I am tinhking of using for my first Craft site also holds lots (~100) of mainly PDFs some for public use and others for members only. They need a fairly simnple way for the end usuer to be able to upload an keep them oraganised.

Would Craft satisfy these criteria?

Cheers - Mark

Answer (score 2):

Should be no problem, Craft has extensive user management capabilities, check https://craftcms.com/features/users & https://craftcms.com/docs/users as well as solid asset management https://craftcms.com/features/assets

Log in to the demo https://demo.craftcms.com/ or do a local install, as long as your test domain has .dev in the url you can fully test Craft with purchasing a license.